# jQuery js file not loading

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, servlets

Why my custom js is loading but jquery-1.11.1.js is not loading, tried placing it in same folder as my custom js(StartPage.js), but still on firebug console its showing not found.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/StartPage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <%@ include file="/html/StartPage.html"%>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try : ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.1.js

Comment: @thecbuilder, not working with this

Comment: simple enough to figure out by looking at source output

Comment: @charlietfl can you elaborate your comment

Comment: path is obviously wrong, so adjust based on output

Comment: if path was wrong then why other .js is loading from the same path, isn't it contradicting

Answer (score 1):

My bad...

I was running the application by right-clicking on index.jsp from eclipse, that's why it was getting confused in resolving js file paths, and StartPage.js was loading from Spring container, as /StartPage was getting resolved from @RequestMapping from the controller.

Now I ran whole project on the server and the path is resolved for all js files(using ${PageContext.request.contextPath}).

Answer (score 0):

Try this path and try clearing cache of broswer

you are missing "js" from your path try the following path

```
 ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.1.js
```

Comment: I tried this combination too after clearing browser cache, but how one js is loading from the same path but another not, and one more thing at eclipse console its giving following warning:
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRolls/js/jquery-1.11.1.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: try using relative path as /js/jquery-1.11.1.js